# Issue with FCKEditor in ATG Merchandising

Tags: fckeditor, atg, bcc, oracle-commerce

I have a problem. In BCC ATG 11.2 I've configured default HTML asset editor for Big String Plain Text according this article http://obed33.blogspot.com.by/2015/04/how-to-change-wysiwyg-editor-on-bcc.html. But when I am trying edit big string (Article asset for example), only big frame for editing text is opening. There is no icons for fonts, neither tabs "Source" and so on. I guess, FCKEditor doesn't starting. Can anybody help me with this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: How does this relate to programming?

Comment: This relate to the Oracle Commerce Platform that I have the title